# Vector of Generic Structs in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

I am creating an entity component system in Rust, and I would like to be able to store a `Vec` of components for each different `Component` type:

```
pub trait Component {}

struct ComponentList<T: Component> {
    components: Vec<T>,
}
```

Is it possible to create a collection of these `ComponentList`s?

```
struct ComponentManager {
    component_lists: Vec<ComponentList<_>>, // This does not work
}
```

This is intended to make it faster to retrieve a list of a certain `Component` type, as all instances of a certain type of component will be in the same `ComponentList`.

Comment: Do you mean a `Vec<ComponentList<C>>` where `C: Component` is the same class for the whole vector, or a  `Vec<ComponentList<c>>` for each component type `c` you have?

Comment: I meant a `Vec<ComponentList<c>>` for each `impl` of `Component` (the latter)

Comment: In that case you need to either keep an attribute to each implementation in your struct, or have a vector with dynamic dispatch (as in the first answer seen below).

Comment: Do you think you could clarify how exactly I would keep an attribute to each implementation?

Comment: `struct ComponentManager { component1: Component1, component2: Component2, ... }`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a trait that each `ComponentList<T>` will implement but that will hide that `T`. In that trait, define any methods you need to operate on the component list (you will not be able to use `T`, of course, you'll have to use trait objects like `&Component`).

```
trait AnyComponentList {
    // Add any necessary methods here
}

impl<T: Component> AnyComponentList for ComponentList<T> {
    // Implement methods here
}

struct ComponentManager {
    component_lists: Vec<Box<AnyComponentList>>,
}
```

---

If you would like to have efficient lookup of a `ComponentList<T>` based on `T` from the `ComponentManager`, you might want to look into [`anymap`](https://crates.io/crates/anymap) or [`typemap`](https://crates.io/crates/typemap) instead. `anymap` provides a simple map keyed by the type (i.e. you use a type `T` as the key and store/retrieve a value of type `T`). `typemap` generalizes `anymap` by associated keys of type `K` with values of type `K::Value`.