# Dynamically-typed entity component system in Rust

Tags: rust, game-development, type-systems, entity-component-system

## The Problem

I am building an entity component system for a game engine that I'm trying to build, and I'm not quite sure how to proceed in a strict typed language, in this case, Rust.

I'd like the component types to be arbitrary structs that could contain any type of state about the entity, but have no knowledge of the behavior. That way, for example, an entity could contain `Position`, `Hitbox`, and `Velocity` components, but the physics subsystem could be changed or swapped out separately, without having to modify anything about those components.

I'd also like to make it possible to add new component types from outside of the module. This would allow a new game mod to add its own custom component to existing entities without having to modify the core code of the game.

I'm fairly new to Rust, and have done limited work in C++, so I might be taking the wrong approach entirely, and if so, I'd appreciate advice on better ways to solve this problem.

In a language without a strict type system (and that I'm more familiar with), like JavaScript, I can have an array of entities that hold a collection of components of arbitrary type, and then do runtime type-checking to get the data:

```js
class Position {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}

class Velocity {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}

const world = [
  [
    Position(0, 0, 0),
    Velocity(0.25, 0.1, 1.2)
  ]
]

const physicsSystem = (world = []) => world.map((entity = []) => {
  const velocity = entity.find((component) => component instanceof Velocity)
  return velocity != null ? entity.map((component) => component instanceof Position
    ? Position(component.x + velocity.x, component.y + velocity.y, component.z + velocity.z)
    : component
  ) : component
})

window.setInterval(() => world = physicsSystem(world), 100)
```

In the above example, the entities can contain any types of components, and the systems that process them can retrieve the specific components that they depend on, access their concrete properties directly, and then modify the components. Outside code could also add a totally unknown component to one of the entities, and the physics component wouldn't need to be changed to accomodate it. This is the same behavior that I want to have in my rust ECS.

As a side-note, because games require a more high-performance solution than my example javascript would provide, I'd like to minimize pointer indirection, hash table lookups, memory allocation, and optimize data locality as much as possible, but naturally optimization is second to functionality. My example code ignores these optimizations.

## What I've Been Trying

I've considered creating a hashmap of `ComponentStorage<T>`, where `ComponentStorage` is a trait that allows me to abstract the underlying data structure used to store the components. A `State` struct would contain a `HashMap<ComponentStorage<std::any::TypeId, T>>`. The specific storage could be looked up by the TypeId hash, then using the ComponentStorage trait, I could retrieve a `Option<T>` from that storage by the entity ID, and then access whatever properties `T` contains.

This does not work, however, because the type T will be different for each item in the `HashMap`, and I can't erase the type parameter by creating a single trait to implement for each variation of type parameter (as suggested in this similar question: [Vector of Generic Structs in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064700/vector-of-generic-structs-in-rust)) because I need to access the concrete type T in the systems that process the entities.

I could potentially implement something similar to my example JavaScript by using `Any` to store components, but my understanding is that using `Any` on arbitrary custom structs means no adjacent storage, and pointer indirection galore. I don't mean to prematurely optimize, but I'm hesitant to go down this route to prototype it because it doesn't seem like these limitations of `Any` can be overcome without totally rewriting it again later.

Since pointer indirection **must** obviously happen in order to not hard code types into this system, I'm hoping to have the collections of components, rather than the components themselves, be polymorphic, while at the same time being able to access the items contained in a given collection by their concrete types.

Any help you can offer me here, I'd be eternally grateful for. Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of [Specs](https://specs.amethyst.rs/)?

Comment: @FrancisGagné I'd heard of Amethyst, but I'd never looked into how they solved this problem. I may end up just using their library instead of reinventing the wheel, but for the sake of learning, I'm still curious how they managed to keep a dynamic collection of different component storages. I'll have to do some research into this. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to have objects with different types in inside the same container: pointer indirection galore.

Actually JavaScript engine do exactly the same thing for you behind the scene.

Comment: I'll clarify my question a bit. Yes, I do know that I need pointer indirection *somewhere* in my code, but since a game will iterate over thousands to millions of components per tick, it seems like it'd be better to keep all components of one type together in a collection, that way they can occupy adjacent memory, and then I only need to follow a pointer to the collection, and then index into each component from there. If the collections have the same type but hold different component types, that would mean each component access would follow a pointer.